# Exercise in an abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Supose we have an exact sequence $$A\overset{f}\longrightarrow B\overset{g}\rightarrow C\overset{h}\rightarrow D$$ in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Is it true that $f$ is an epimorphism if and only if $h$ is a monomorphism?

It is clear that for any category of modules this is true.

Answer (score 7):

$f$ epi $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathrm{im}(f)=B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\ker(g)=B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $g=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathrm{im}(g)=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\ker(h)=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $h$ mono.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be an epimorphism. If the image of $f$ is the kernel of $g$ then $g$ is constant and then the image of $g$ being the kernel of $h$ is trivial which is enough to have $h$ as an monomorphism.

Let $h$ be a monomorphism, then the image of $g$ is constant, hence $f$ is surjective.

Comment: "the image of $g$ is constant" and "$f$ is surjective" are not precise.

Comment: "in the background" or "little under the surface" are the hypothesis @MartinBrandenburg